# Python, print with format a tuple, not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

Here is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

def goodDifference(total, partial, your_points, his_points):

    while (total - partial >= your_points - his_points):
        partial = partial+1
        your_points = your_points+1

        return (partial, your_points, his_points)

def main():
     total = int(raw_input('Enter the total\n'))
     partial = int(raw_input('Enter the partial\n'))
     your_points = int(raw_input('Enter your points\n'))
     his_points = int(raw_input('Enter his points\n'))
     #print 'Partial {}, yours points to insert {}, points of the other player {}'.format(goodDifference(total, partial, your_points, his_points))
     #print '{} {} {}'.format(goodDifference(total, partial, your_points, his_points))
     print goodDifference(total, partial, your_points, his_points)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

The two commented print-with-format don't work, when executing it reports this error: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`.
The last print (not commented), works fine.
I've read many examples of format strings in Python and I can't understand why my code is not working.

My python version is 2.7.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.format()` requires individual arguments, and you are passing a tuple as a *single* argument. Thus, it substitutes the tuple into the first `{}` and then there are no more items left for the next one. To pass the tuple as individual arguments, [unpack](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) it:

```
print '{} {} {}'.format(*goodDifference(total, partial, your_points, his_points))
```

Comment: what is the * doing in this case?

Comment: Unpacking the tuple into multiple arguments. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Now perfect ... *This answer is useful*

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just printout the values in the tuple?

```
t = goodDifference(total, partial, your_points, his_points)
print '{', t[0], '} {', t[1], '} {', t[2], '}'
```